# How to do this layout from bootstrap 3.3 in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having troubles understanding new float based grid system.

How can I make this code, perfectly working with bootstrap v3.3 work with modern bootstrap?

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>#9 (squeeze right)</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="well"> 
          A
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 pull-right">
        <div class="well tall"> 
          B (keep right)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-left">
        <div class="well"> 
          C
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>  
</div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/siUcTuNhUy (Example # 9)

Comment: I would be exactly the same, apart from the `col-xs-12` being converted to just `col-12`, as well as using `float-left/right` instead of `pull`

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough in Bootstrap v4

You can take a look at the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#utilities)

> Added `.float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}` classes for responsive floats and removed `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` since they’re redundant to `.float-left` and `.float-right`.

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>#9 (squeeze right)</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="well">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 float-right">
      <div class="well tall">
        B (keep right)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 float-left">
      <div class="well">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was my firs attempt, but it doesn't work this way. Because now in Bootstrap 4 you height of A and B will be equal, and I want to place A and C on the same 'level' as B like in example that I provided.